# Como realizar SI.ND(BUSCARV()....) en PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Buenas me gustaria saber si es posible realizar esta formula en PHPExcel

```
=SI.ND(BUSCARV(A46;Dat_STATUS_EXP;2;FALSO);0)+Q46
```

He observado que la función `SI.ND` no la podria usar, ya que no existe para excel 2007.

Yo he  intentado hacer algo así, pero no me funciona.

```
setCellValue('P'.$i,'=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'.$i.'Dat_STATUS_EXP;2;FALSO);0)+Q'.$i)
```

A ver si a alguien se le ocurre alguna forma, ya sea con otra formula si es necesario, pero que de el mismo resultado.

Comment: No se que pretendes usar, pero a lo mejor puedes hacer la operación en PHP antes de mandarlo a las celdas.

Comment: pretendo usar la libreria PHPExcel. La formula en definitiva lo que hace es Buscar una fecha, en una tabla de otra hoja. y se le suma a todo esto  se le suma un número

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, era un error de los ;

Aqui dejo la sintaxis, por si a alguien le sirve

```
setCellValue('P'.$i,'=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A'.$i.',Dat_STATUS_EXP,2,FALSE),0)+Q'.$i);
```

Un saludo!